# Inner Join in R returning larger dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

I'm attempting to inner join two tables (keep only rows where the "join by" variable is in both tables) but my resulting table is bigger than my original table and I'm not sure why.

For example, I am trying to merge `enroll_dsnp` and service to get `serv_enroll`. The goal is to use this join to eliminate rows in enroll_dnsp that are not represented in service. However, the resulting `serv_enroll` files is larger (15k) than the `enroll_dsnp` file (14k). Why is this and how can I fix my issue?

I've tried the following solutions:

```
serv_enroll <- merge(x = enroll_dsnp, y = service, by = "Contract_State_County", 
                     all = FLASE, all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE, no.dups = TRUE) 
serv_enroll <- enroll_dsnp %>% inner_join(service, by = "Contract_State_County")
```

[image]

Comment: the "Contract_State_County" in "service" seems not to be unique -> therefore generating duplication of lines during join operations in "enroll_dspn"... you can check this using dplyr::count(service, Contract_State_County) %>% dplyr::arrange(desc(n))... this will show how many occurrences of each "Contract_State_County" are "service" in decreasing order (if any is larger then 1 this would indicate the problem I am suspecting from you description)

Comment: If your goal is "to eliminate rows in enroll_dnsp that are not represented in servic" `dplyr::semi_join()` might help!

Comment: The semi_join that @TimTeaFan is suggesting is equivalent to a filter with the %in% operator in this way:  semi_join_df <- enroll_dsnp %>%
  filter(Contract_State_County %in% service$Contract_State_County)

Comment: @hachiko @benzinga: I mistakenly said `semi_join` but meant `anti_join` since it is about rows in `df_a` which are not present in `df_b`.

Comment: Good catch on this